# Jquery Range Slider How to Create Own Sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a range slider with jquery. I have one slider for numbers which works and a second slider with string values. The second slider only works if the letters are in the correct order of the alphabet.

When alph = ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"] then it does the job. But when I try to have my own sequence like alph = ["F", "H", "D", "G", "E", "I", "J"] then it doesn't behave like I thought it would be.

How do I get my own order? For example alph = ["F", "H", "D", "G", "E", "I", "J"]. So when I slide the values to H-J then the table should display columns with H, D, G, E, I, J.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  step: 0.01,
  min: 0.00,
  max: 2.00,
  values: [ 0.00, 2.00 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the     sliders
 $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ].toFixed(2) + " ct" + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ].toFixed(2) + " ct" );

    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
           //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

           if (j == 2) {             // if 3rd column
               if ($(col).html() >= ui.values[ 0 ] && $(col).html() <= ui.values[ 1 ]) {
                   // if in interval
                   $(row).removeClass('slider1Hide').trigger("update");
               } else {
                   $(row).addClass('slider1Hide').trigger("update");
               }
           }
       }  
    }          
  }
});

$( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ).toFixed(2) + " ct" +
  " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ).toFixed(2) + " ct" );


var alph = ["F", "H", "D", "G", "E", "I", "J"];
$( "#slider-range3" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 6,
  values: [ 0 , 6 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders
    $( "#amount3" ).val( alph[ui.values[ 0 ]] + " - " + alph[ui.values[ 1 ]] );

    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows (we SKIP the first row: counter starts at 1!)
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
           //iterate through columns: if first column not in range: HIDE, else SHOW

           if (j == 4) {             // if 5th column
               if ($(col).html() >= alph[ui.values[ 0 ]] && $(col).html() <= alph[ui.values[ 1 ]]) {
                   // if in interval
                   $(row).removeClass('slider3Hide').trigger("update");
               } else {
                   $(row).addClass('slider3Hide').trigger("update");
               }
           }
       }  
    }          
  }
});

$( "#amount3" ).val(alph[$( "#slider-range3" ).slider( "values", 0 )] +
  " - " + alph[$( "#slider-range3" ).slider( "values", 1 )] );
});
```

The html table is pretty basic. The only special thing about it, it's that it has an id and a class name.

css is only:

```
.slider1Hide {
    display: none;
}

.slider3Hide {
    display: none;
}
```

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by using a different approach. The code in my first post only works for arrays with a correct order (for example, a, b c,...z or hello1, hello2,...hellon) or if you use a slider with a single drag handle.

But what if you want your own order?

I used a normal range slider, the one that uses numbers and I used CSS to convert the numbers to letters.

This is not the most beautiful approach, but I finally got it working.